# Mechanical Ventilation filters: DIY with bulk material

Tags: ventilation, replacement, filter, dust

My home has a mechanical ventilation / heat recovery system ([this one](https://www.zehnder-systems.ch/it/dispositivi-di-ventilazione/apparecchi-di-ventilazione-superiori-100-m%C2%B3/dispositivi-inferiori-600-m%C2%B3h/zehnder-comfoair-350)) with two filters that have to be changed at least every six months. I've seen that they quickly become dirty and clogged with dust particles long before the recommended six months.

The original filters (part #400100084) cost about 60 euros, and even third-party compatible filters aren't much cheaper. What irks me is that a roll of bulk material, suitable for dozens of filters, shouldn't cost much more than 10 euros, yielding considerable savings and cleaner air due to more frequent replacement (I'd like to do that every two months).

The filters currently sold have a fancy plastic holder, but those in my MVHR unit are simply a rectangle of polyester non-woven cloth stretched between two metal rods; making them from bulk shouldn't present a problem at all.

The problem is that I've not been able to find a manufacturer that sells a roll or sheets of materal with the same characteristics, that don't seem so esoteric to me:

- Anti-pollen filter F7 / ISO ePM1 ≥ 50 %, thickness 2-3 mm
- Filter G4 / ISO Coarse ≥ 60 %, thickness 2-3 mm

Either kind will work; the catch here is the thickness. I've found rolls with the same characteristics, and the 10 euro price mentioned above, but far thicker (10 mm and more). I've tried google, amazon, ebay and local vendors but apparently I'm not using the right queries.

Should I abandon my idea? Can somebody point me in the right direction to find this kind of filter material?

Comment: Search for the manufacturer of the material - expecting specialist stuff on Amazon or Ebay is the issue here.

Comment: @Solar Mike that's why I also tried all kinds of Google searches, and checked the websites of firms doing AC / filtering, to no avail. There's no manufacturer logo, stamp or part number on the original filters (aside from the Zahnder part number that I indicated).

Comment: Perhaps ask someone at a local HVAC specialist shop?

Comment: While I sympathize with your plight, this is, effectively a "help me shop" question. We might find you a supplier today, but they may stop carrying the product next week, meaning that the Q&A become useless. That's why shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: @FreeMan I need help finding the right queries, not the right shop. For instance, I recently discovered that "G4" is an obsolete designation, and I'll have better luck with "ISO Coarse 60%". Also instead of looking for "thickness 3mm" maybe it's better to use weight (i.e. 5 gr / m2). Is "non-woven fiber cloth" a good description or is there a technical term that is more fitting...?